# Derivative: When x > 0, $\frac{d}{dx} f_1(x) < \frac{d}{dx} f_2(x)$ ??

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I have a question regarding the derivative of two functions.
I am wondering if the following statement is true:

If the derivative of a function (say, $f_1$) is smaller than that of the other function (say, $f_2$), then there exists a case when $f_1$ < $f_2$.

Mathematically speaking,

If $\frac{d}{dx} f_1(x) < \frac{d}{dx} f_2(x)$ given that $x > 0$, then is it true that $f_1 < f_2$ given that $x > 0$ & $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ both are positive strictly?

Thank you in advance!!

(added) I know that if x < 0, then this statement does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Look at $f_1=\frac{1}{x}$ and $f_2=\frac{-1}{x}$ for $x>0$.

Comment: Hi Anurag, Thanks for your comment. I just edited the post. If $x > 0$ strictly, and both $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ also have strictly positive values, then would the statement be true?

Comment: The question now requires that both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are strictly positive, but I'll note that this doesn't change anything: modifying the example slightly, consider $f_1(x)=2+\frac{1}{x+1}$ and $f_2(x)=2-\frac{1}{x+1}$.

Comment: @rudgus51998 I was about to add more text after you edited the original question but JunderscoreH's answer takes care of that very nicely.